# Knockout update computed value after blur

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have bound an observable to one input and I would like to trigger observable value update *after input looses focus*. In this simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wj11c26c/. you can see that it behaves kinda strangely. If you try to delete (backspace) characters in it will work, but when you change the actual number, e.g. `1000 to 100` it will immediately update its value to `100 €`.

I have tried to use `valueUpdate` with `blur` but it keeps updating...

How can I trigger value change after blur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `value` binding instead of a `textInput` binding when you don't want the immediate character by character updates that `textInput` provides:

```html
<input class="form-control input-lg pull-right hidden-xs" 
       data-bind="value: totalFormat" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wj11c26c/1/

Comment: Thanks, that works. I didnt notice textInput provides instant updates